# How can I resolve an instance based on a open generic type?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, structuremap, structuremap4

Currently I'm trying to reimplement some code code written in Castle Windsor in structuremap.

This code:

```
Component.For(typeof(IMongoCollection<>))
  .UsingFactoryMethod(
   (k, c) => MongoResolver.ResolveCollection(k, c.RequestedType)));
```

Does the following: When IMongoCollection is being called, resolve the concrete collection.

I tried to do this in structuremap with:

```
For(typeof(IMongoCollection<>)).Use("test", x =>
{
     SOME MAGIC!
});
```

But I cant figure out what to do in the magic part.

Comment: Something like this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671078/registering-method-on-generic-factory-with-structuremap

Comment: Not completely, but this link set me onto a trail that led me to https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/blob/977b1784632484473d09d3724f2435a73437e49b/src/StructureMap.Testing/Acceptance/builder_for_open_generic_type.cs And that fixed it.

Comment: Consider adding a self-answer?